# How would I be of making a script that shows subtitles when a touch function triggers?

Tags: roblox

How do I make a script if somebody touched a brick and then maybe a GUI then shows subtitles for like a few seconds and goes the downside of your screen? (like credits after a movie)

Comment: See [ask]. [SO] is a question-and-answer site. The idea is you tell us what you want to do, show with a [mcve] what you ahve tried, and tell us what results you got. A single general sentence will not get any traction here.

Answer (score 0):

I know the first part of creating this but I do not know the GUI part. For the first part, I think you should do something like this...

```
local Part = script.Parent -- This would define the part that is to be touched.

function onTouch(Brick) -- Starts the onTouch function which sends us "Brick", the triggering object.

local Player = Brick.Parent:findFirstChild("Humanoid") -- Finds Humanoid in Brick.

    if (Player ~= nil) then -- Checks if the player is a real Player.

    print("Hello World"")

    end

end
```

Replace the **print("Hello World!")** line with the code from the GUI if you know it.

Regards, Shay!